# Rendering a list with views combining user + a content type

Tags: views, comments

hello is there any way i can create a view with a list of users who are member of a group [organic group modules, latest version]

The view must also be able to display another content type so Inline ajax comment that i am able to use comments in that content type which is  required in order to use this module [Inline ajax comment](http://drupal.org/project/inline_comments)

The problem that i am facing is this module works when i create a view of content type, but when i create a view of user type it does not work....

Any solution... ?? thanks in advance ...

Comment: can you provide more information on what isn't working in your view? Are you not seeing any data or are you not able to add the user fields that you want to the view?

Comment: I want to be able to use this Inline ajax comment in views>add new>show>users but the module only works in views>add new>show>content. here is a screencast -> http://geoffhankerson.com/node/177